# How to load data as soon as welcome jsp gets loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have a index.jsp which is a welcome page for my web application. Now, as soon as I hit the url, I need to display a table populated with data coming from backend services through ajax call. I have mapped the URL using spring mvc and already verified that controller method is getting a hit.Following is my jquery snippet,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var body = $("body");

    $.ajax({
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/product/display",

        type : "GET",

        success : function(data) {
            alert("alert");
        }

    });
})
```

I have observed that even alert is not working. Dont know what is going wrong here.

Comment: Add an `error` callback to see what error comes back. Have you checked that the URL is actually the right one?

Comment: URL is getting a hit..i confirmed by debugging i eclipse.

Comment: What does does the developer tools' network tab say?

Comment: error:Not Found..                                                         I guess the reason is that i am expecting result to get displayed on index.jsp but my ajax url is pointing towards some other difference,i.e.display. Please guide me about how to get data on the same jsp page irrespective of the ajax url

Comment: The answer is probably using an absolute URL.